# Gradle how to merge files with PropertiesFileContentMerger?

Tags: gradle, merge, properties-file

Gradle How to merge two properties files?

```
war {
   from zipTree("foo.war") {

       filesMatching("bar.properties") {
           // how to merge with /path/hello.properties?
           // i.e. add all the properties in hello.properties to bar.properties
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: i see you are asking loads of questions here about gradle, most of them are already answered on stack, or easy to find on google, did you consider doing some research, as well your questions are not clear and are not [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please consider following those rules to help us to help you.

Comment: I could not find related answer on google. This one is merging files directly into a war.

Comment: then maybe try to explain and give us some examples, what you already tried some indication what you trying to achieve, if your question would be asked differently probably there would be some answers or at least comments, believe me.